# Разделить на  слоги

Tags: перенос

Помогите, пожалуйста, разделить на слоги для переноса слово "БОЯЛАСЬ".
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На слоги? Или для переноса? Правда, в этом слове совпадает деление: бо-я-лась